# Segmenation fault in malloc()?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, stack-trace

I am getting a segmentation fault inside of the malloc() routine. Here is the stacktrace from gdb:

```
#0  0x00007ffff787e882 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff787fec6 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7882a45 in malloc () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0x0000000000403ab0 in xmalloc (size=1024) at global.c:14
#4  0x00000000004020fb in processConnectionQueue (arguments=0x60a4e0)
    at connection.c:117
#5  0x00007ffff7bc4e9a in start_thread ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff78f24bd in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

What's going on? What could cause malloc() to segfault?

EDIT: Here is the code from xmalloc(). It's pretty standard, and as you can see from the stacktrace it's calling malloc with a size of 1024.

```
void* xmalloc(size_t size)
{
    void* result = malloc(size);
    if(!result)
    {
        if(!size)
        {
            result = malloc(1);
        }
        if(!result)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory of size %zu\n", size);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And line 117 in connection.c:

```
        item->readBuffer = xmalloc(kInitialPacketBufferSize);
```

Comment: Would help, if you post your code!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `processConnectionQueue` function, at least the lines around 117.

Comment: Can you post code, particularly prior to the call to `malloc()`?

Comment: If you want to solve it yourself, you can use the `up` command of GDB to go up the call stack, and when you're at position 4 (which is your function) you can examine all variables to see that they look okay.

Comment: Post your code at the line 117.

Comment: Code prior to the call to `xmalloc()`?

Comment: It's a server, there is a lot going on. This is in the routine to allocate things for a new connection.

Comment: I think the bug have been hided in your code before malloc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are most likely seeing the effect of an error elsewhere in your code, that access memory outside an allocation. If you are lucky enough, your code can touch some of the internal values malloc uses to track allocations.

If you have the possibility, try linking your code with an allocation checker like libefence or similar, and use this to locate the real problem.

Comment: Using libefence, I found one of my pointers is set to 0xff. That could easily be a malloc state variable. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the line

```
#3  0x0000000000403ab0 in xmalloc (size=1024) at global.c:14
```

the global.c for the size=1024.
and also you can use some tools as *Wegge* mentioned to detect some issue regrading this segfault.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three basic causes of this.

1. You overran the item returned by malloc() and wrote something before its beginning or after its end.
2. You freed something twice, which in a way is a special case of
3. You freed something that wasn't a malloc() result.

Any of these actions will corrupt the malloc)) heap, which causes it to malfunction.